# Matrix Logarithm in Base 2

Tags: matlab, matrix, logarithm

`Logm()` takes the matrix logarithm, and `log2()` takes the logarithm base 2 of each element of a matrix.

I'm trying to compute the Von Neumann entropy, which involves the base 2 matrix logarithm. How do I do this?

Comment: The matrix logarithm is an inverse of the matrix exponential. Could you clarify what you mean by "base 2" here? If you define the matrix exponential with base 2 as `expm(log(2) .* A)`, then you may want to use `logm(B) ./ log(2)`.

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to the [Von Neumann Entropy in 31 and 32](http://pages.uoregon.edu/svanenk/solutions/Mixed_states.pdf). I am not quite sure what it means - I just know that base 2 is required for the bit unit.

Comment: If you define the logarithm via an eigendecomposition as in the document, then the change of base carries over from the change of base of the eigenvalue-wise logarithm, which is a division by `log(2)` in this case; hence, my suggestion should work.

Comment: Thank you @Thales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define the matrix exponential "with base 2" as `B = expm(log(2) .* A)`, or if you analogously directly define the matrix logarithm "with base 2" via an eigendecomposition with the standard logarithm of base 2 applied eigenvalue-wise, then you can obtain a corresponding base 2 matrix logarithm by dividing by `log(2)`:

```
A = logm(B) ./ log(2)
```